# How to prevent new Terminal windows opening in same directory?

Tags: command-line

Hitting `Ctrl-Shift-N` when an existing terminal window has focus opens a new terminal window with the same working directory as the old terminal window.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: With `cd [Enter]` you get back to your default (home) directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> instead `Ctrl+Shift+N`..
This will open a new "Terminal window" in your $HOME directory, no matter if you have opened another "Terminal window" in.. eg: `/var`

Cheers.

Comment: That seems to work! However did you find that key combination though?

Comment: In System Settings > Keyboard > Shorcuts > Launchers (Launch Termianl = Ctrl+Alt+T) This is by default.